# How to send client certificate with api request to server in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, postman, vscode-extensions

I have an example API with is secured by SSL cert, I tried a lot to send the cert along with the XMLHttpRequest but that's not working then I tried with Postman after adding the cert in settings and got that working fine.

Then I checked the code sample for Javascript in Postman, i found there is no code related to added certificate, How Postman is sending the added cert with the request?

How can I send the SSL cert with XMLHttpRequest in VSCode?

[image]

[image]